# Mongoose duplicate declaration

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model that looks like this:

```
var conversationsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    start_date: Date,
    users: [{
        user_id: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        socket_id: String
    }]
});
```

I want to find a conversation between two users and so I use the following code.

```
Conversation.findOne({
            'users.user_id': {$in: thisUsers.user_id},
            'users.user_id': {$in: thisPartner.user_id}
});
```

This works find. However, it looks wrong and like there is a better way of doing this. My editor also says 'duplicate declaration'.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Can you try Conversation.findOne({'users.user_id': {$in: thisUsers.user_id, thisPartner.user_id} }); ?

Comment: That syntax threw and error and so I tried putting the items in an array, like: 'users.user_id': {$in: [thisUsers.user_id, thisPartner.user_id]}. I then changed one of the user's IDs in the Conversations and it still found one even though one was wrong but the other was right.

Comment: Do you need to find the rows when it has both users id and partner id ? If yes, then you need all operator. Can you try Conversation.findOne({'users.user_id': {$all: [thisUsers.user_id, thisPartner.user_id]} }); ?

Comment: There is two objects inside the users array. Each object will have a user_id. I need to make sure both user_ids match the ones coming in. My solution was to use the $and operator.  https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/and/

Comment: that will do so will $all https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/all/

Answer (score 0):

The duplicate de `'duplicate declaration'` is due to using the same key (`'users.user_id'`) twice in the query object (previous value is discarded).

You can use [$in Operator to Match Values](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/in/#use-the-in-operator-to-match-values):

```
Conversation.findOne({
  $and: [ 
    {'users.user_id': {$in: [ thisUsers.user_id ]}},
    {'users.user_id': {$in: [ thisPartner.user_id ]}}
  ]
});
```

or simply:

```
Conversation.findOne({
  $and: [ 
    {'users.user_id': thisUsers.user_id},
    {'users.user_id': thisPartner.user_id}
  ]
});
```

or better [$all](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/all/#equivalent-to-and-operation):

```
Conversation.findOne({
  'users.user_id': {$all: [ thisUsers.user_id, thisPartner.user_id ]}
});
```